# Contour plot with irregular grid with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, contour

I want to use [Plotly's contour function](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/) to produce a contour plot but with arbitrary `x,y` pairs for each `z`. I.e. I want to have something like this:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[1.1,2.2,3.3],[1,1.5,3]]
y = [[1,1.1,1],[2,2,2.2],[3,3.3,3]]
z = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

[Matplotlib's contour function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) seems to support this. Is it possible to achieve this with Plotly?

Comment: Is this the code you are looking for? `import plotly.graph_objects as go;fig = go.Figure(data = go.Contour(
        x = list(set([1,2,3,1.1,2.2,3.3,1,1.5,3])),
        y = list(set([1,1.1,1,2,2,2.2,3,3.3,3])),
        z = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    ));
fig.show()`

Comment: No, that produces a plot with x and y taking values in `{1,2,3}`, I need to use arbitrary values. Your code produces the same as `go.Contour(x = [1,2,3], y = [1,2,3], z = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`.